# Finding number of digits before a decimal point in java

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have declared the variable for the double I'm using:

```
z= 345.876;
```

Now I want to display the number of digits that come before the decimal point. I tried to do the following:

```
String string_form = new Double(z).toString().subString(0,string_form.indexOf('.'));
double t = Double.valueOf(string_form);
```

I get an error saying: 'The method subString(int, int) is undefined for the type String'

Then a quick fix shows to change it small case s as: substring. However the error then changes to the string, 'string_form' which says it's not initialized. Any ideas on what to do?

And also how would I modify that to find the number of digits that come after a number? I know in the part

```
.indexOf('.')
```

I'd replace the decimal point with a number but how would i change it so that it displays how many digits come AFTER the number, not before? thanks. and yes I have imported the decimalformat text lang.

Comment: Not to change the question, but you should use Math.log rather than count digits in a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use string_form before you have actually created it.

If you break

```
String string_form = new Double(z).toString().substring(0,string_form.indexOf('.'));
double t = Double.valueOf(string_form);
```

into

```
String string_temp = new Double(z).toString();
String string_form = string_temp.substring(0,string_temp.indexOf('.'));
double t = Double.valueOf(string_form);
```

Then it should work.

To get the numbers after the decimal point just take the digits from period until the end of the number.

```
String string_temp = new Double(z).toString();
String string_form = string_temp.substring(string_temp.indexOf('.'), string_temp.length());
double t = Double.valueOf(string_form);
```

As others have pointed out though, there are many better ways than converting to string and checking for period and reconverting.

Comment: Ah I see.Thanks.  The syntax errors seem to be solved but the variable t apparently is shown as not being used locally, so it doesn't read the variable sadly. Would adding surpresswarnings help?

Comment: No you don't need to do that. The warning is because you have created a variable t but haven't used it. After doing anything with it (ie. using it in some line, printing it, etc.) that warning will disappear.

Comment: Hi, Brendan. Your written code work for selecting digits before decimal point but it's not working for selecting digits after decimal point. Here is my code if you can help me out .                `String getAcreIntoString = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(acre)).toString();
                        String getAcreDigit = getAcreIntoString.substring( getAcreIntoString.indexOf('.'), getAcreIntoString.length());`

Answer (score 3):

The number of decimal digits before the decimal point is given by

```
(int)Math.log10(z)+1
```

The number of decimal digits after it is imprecise and depends on how much precision you use when converting to decimal. Floating-point values don't have decimal places, they have binary places, and the two are incommensurable.

Answer (score 1):

just convert the double to a string. find the index of . with `indexOf`. get the length of the string. subtract the index of . from the length and you should have the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string_form = Double(z).toString();
int index = string_form.indexOf('.');
double d = Double.parse(string_form.substring(0, index+1));
```

If the numbers are small, you could try

```
int i = (int) z;
```

or

```
long l = Math.round(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `string_form` in the expression `string_form.indexOf('.')`, but it's not initialized yet, because it's only set *after* the call to `substring()`. You need to store the value of `toString()` in a temporary variable so you can access it in the call to `substring()`. Something like this

```
String stringForm = new Double(z).toString();
stringForm = stringForm.substring(stringForm.indexOf('.'));
```

There are other and better ways to do this, however. `Math.floor(z)` or even just a cast `(long)z` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Could do this, for examble:

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(possibleBirths).split(".")[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the next thing:

```
Double z = 345.876;
int a = t.intValue();
int counter = 0;
while(a != 0) {
  counter++;
  a = a / 10;  }
System.out.println(counter);
```